# Unable to connect to WiFi - Dell Vostro 2420

Tags: wireless

I got a Dell Vostro 2420 laptop yesterday. It was connecting to WiFi perfectly fine. Today, I am unable to connect to the WiFi network. The wireless icon also doesn't show any curved lines.

I am using Ubuntu for the first time so I don't know anything about it. Here's the output of rfkill list all:

```
rfkill list all
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I still cannot connect.

Answer (score 0):

you have first to deactivate the driver you installed from `jockey`, 
and then you can use `ndisgtk`
if you have your wireless driver for windows this program will create a driver for linux starting from Windows driver 
if it did not work you can see [this](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices) for detecting you wireless card then download the driver from [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download)

or finally if those did not worked try this
 `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
 or this 
`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` in the command line

Comment: @ali...thankx but i didnt get the head and tail of it...jockey???? ndisgtk

Comment: those are names of programmes you can find them in USC (ubuntu software center) `jockey` is `Additional driver` and `ndisgtk` is `wireless driver from windows`